# Are REST Webservices stateful?

Tags: rest, web-services, state, stateless, stateful

We are talking about REST Webservices in my university right now.
There came the terms "Application" and "Interaction" up.
I totally understand Interaction, but not quite Application.
Does anybody know what Application means in the context of REST Webservices?

There came the thesis "REST Webservices" are stateful up.
This was explained with self describing messages.
The argument was, that in the self describing messages the required data format is described.
I do not find any proof of that on the Internet, rather the opposite.

Can anybody explain both terms and explain to me why REST Webservices should be stateful?

Cheers,
Henrik

Answer (score 0):

Heuristic: anytime you are thinking about [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), consider the web as an example.  How does it work with web pages and browsers?

---

State:

Resources (web pages) are stateful.  The representations (bytes) can change over time.

Messages (http requests and responses) are [stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) - you don't need to know anything about "session" or "context" to understand the message.  Alternative spelling - the meaning of a request is completely independent of any previous request.

Fielding discusses applications and application state when discussing the [REST data view](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_3_3)

> ...  looking-up a word in an on-line dictionary is one application, as is touring through a virtual museum, or reviewing a set of class notes to study for an exam. Each application defines goals for the underlying system, against which the system's performance can be measured....
>
> An application's state is therefore defined by its pending requests, the topology of connected components (some of which may be filtering buffered data), the active requests on those connectors, the data flow of representations in response to those requests, and the processing of those representations as they are received by the user agent.
>
> An application reaches a steady-state whenever it has no outstanding requests; i.e., it has no pending requests and all of the responses to its current set of requests have been completely received or received to the point where they can be treated as a representation data stream. For a browser application, this state corresponds to a "web page," including the primary representation and ancillary representations, such as in-line images, embedded applets, and style sheets. [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_3_3)